# How to prevent all files from copying with Middleman Deploy

Tags: ruby, ftp, middleman

I am deploying a middleman site with [Middleman Deploy](https://github.com/middleman-contrib/middleman-deploy) using the FTP setup. When I deploy, every single file gets copied to the server. Is there a way to skip the overwriting of files that haven't changed? Kind of like an "Overwrite if source is newer" option.

Comment: I don't know of it's possible using FTP, but it's the default behavior for RSync. I highly recommend using that instead.